# Отменить поведение по умолчанию комбинации клавиш js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Нужно отменить поведение по умолчанию комбинации `ctrl + z` и сделать, чтобы эта комбинация делала перенос строки в `<div contenteditable="true"></div>`, сейчас это выглядит так

```
if (e.which === 90 && e.ctrlKey) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(div).html( $(div).html() + '<br>' );
}
```

Ф-ия в которой условие запускает по `keyup`. Сейчас проблема в том, что при нажатии `ctrl + z` комбинация работает по умолчанию (шаг назад), а когда шаг назад уже "некуда делать", тогда только начинает работать мой перенос строки...
Может кто сталкивался, заранее спасибо!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xg3z2p5o/

Comment: Спасибо, не додумался что на keyDown нужно return сделать, то что нужно)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кроме `preventDefault` в данном случае стоит делать и `stopPropagation` (оба сразу можно сделать с помощью `return false`):

```js
var $div = $("div");
$("body").on("keydown", function(e) {
  if (e.which == 90 && e.ctrlKey) {
    $div.html($div.html() + "Z");
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <input type="text" />
    <div></div>
</body>
```